# $this->email->send() return false still email get send

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am sending notification email using code igniter email library. Email sending is working properly but sometime only.

I am using `$this->email->send()` to check that email is send or not. Like:

```
if($this->email->send())
{
    //Success
} else {
    // faile
print_r ( $this->email->print_debugger ( array ('headers','subject') )); 
}
```

#### Problem:

It sounds unreal but I have tested it many time before asking here.
When I execute the code then in my system log it shows that email is `Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.` but When i check the email account then it has that email which my system log say failed. In short `$this->email->send()` is not working for me.

So can anyone suggest any other alternative solution for this problem.

I have also tried to debug it and it shows that it will came to ease and print the debug detail but while in this process email is get send.

In the debug process `$this->email->send()` return `FALSE` but still email get send.

any suggestion regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: Whoever who vote to close it please consider that i have tried many different ways and also added the complete code and tried to debut too. I can't understand why anyone want to close it. If moderator see this please help sir.

Answer (score 0):

if sending email in a loop try

`$this->email->clear();`

before defining email variables

here is an example

```
foreach ($list as $name => $address)
{
        $this->email->clear();

        $this->email->to($address);
        $this->email->from('your@example.com');
        $this->email->subject('Here is your info '.$name);
        $this->email->message('Hi '.$name.' Here is the info you requested.');
        $this->email->send();
}
```

Comment: Not sending in loop dear. Thanks